# my chrome "sleep" extension does not seem to run

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sleep

im very new to javascript and chrome extensions, and fairly new to programming at all.

my manifest.json :

```
{
    "name": "GetUp aSec",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Be healthy, get up!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

my background.js is a function i found online that was promised to run smoother than normal sleep functions
then it sends a message, every 52 minutes.

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

while (true) {
    sleep(52000 * 60).then(() => {
        chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true },
            function (tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 'its been 52 minutes! you should take a break.')
            })
    });
}
```

my content.js is just a listener that would hopefully alert the message.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    alert(request)
})
```

when  i add it to chrome, it doesnt give me any errors, but it also does not do anything. any help??

Comment: `while (true) { /*no control flow statements here*/` that kills the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Open Chrome's task manager and you'll see your extension is eating 100% CPU being stuck in an endless `while` loop.

Switch to the async/await syntax in order to **actually pause the loop's body**:

```js
(async () => {
  while (true) {
    await sleep(52 * 60e3);
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, tabs => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,
        "It's been 52 minutes! You should take a break.");
    });
  }
})();
```

Even better, make your background script load only on demand (["persistent": false](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)) and use [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) API **instead of** the infinite loop with setTimeout.